# How to find or refer to instantinated 3Dobject by coordinates?

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot4

I have a procedural generated map like this (All rooms and tunnels made from planes 2x2m with `instantinate()`):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztQHZ.png)
I want to fill all empty space by cubes. I have a coordinates of all rooms and tunnels, but I think that's too difficult and long way. I want to get a code like this:

```
var coord = Vector3i(0,0,0)
var new_cube
var cube = preload("res://assets/cube.tscn")

for x in range(32):
   coord.x += 2
   for y in range(32):
      if y == 0: crood.z = 0
      coord.z -= 2
      if is_something_on_coordinates(coord): continue
      new_fld=cube.instantiate()
      add_child(new_cube)
      new_cube.global_translate(coord)
```

I tried to find a way to find an object on the coordinates, but all that I found is for 2d canvas or for manually created objects.

Comment: What type of nodes does the cube scene have? I'm wondering if we can tackle this with physics, or if we create some kind of index table.

Comment: Cubes is just a MeshInstance3D that I created on 3D scene and preload them to other scene, that all. Same for planes composing a floor of level.

Comment: What about the rest, what is it that is filling the space where you do not want the cubes?

Comment: Maybe, I didn't say all clearly. I meant that I want to make a walls from cubes, and I don't want a space between the walls. If code will look like I wrote, that will be the most easy way.

Comment: So you have nothing there, which means we have to work with your definition for the rooms and tunnels, right? Ok, how are you defining them? What comes to mind is a random list of rectangles, but I do not know if you any other useful structure (e.g. do you know what is connected to what, or are they sorted by some coordinate). Addendum: I think we can do it with a raster algorithm, I'll post an answer later.

Comment: I have only coordinates, height and width of all of them, and I can make matrix of rooms connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say each one of your rooms have a position and a size.

The idea is as follows: Each room has a range for each of its coordinates, which goes from its position to its position plus size.

Let us say, for example, that we are only looking at the `x` coordinate. Then each room has a range that goes from `position.x` to `position.x + size.x`.

I'll also assume there are no negative sizes, so `position.x + size.x` is greater than `position.x` for any particular room.

Now we can take our current position in `x` and see if it is in the range of any room:

```
var found_room := false
for room in rooms:
    if x > room.position.x and x < room.position.x + room.size.x:
        found_room = true
        break
```

Of course, that only ensures that we are in the x range of the room. We might still be outside of the room in the other coordinate. But if your position is in range for all coordinates, it means it is inside the rectangle. Thus: **repeat the same check for the other coordinate**.

*There are other possible optimizations, but you probably don't need then for your map size. However a common idea is this: building - while generating the rooms - some structures in memory that makes easy finding a room given a position (the simplest of these would be arrays sorted by coordinates, and the more complex involve some kind of space partitioning).*

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted, but that will work.

Comment: @romaji9 Ok, how about this: you draw the rectangles to an image, and the query the color of the pixels. Addendum: How to draw? Either do it in CPU with the `Image` class, or you could use a viewport texture (in the viewport you could make the picture with nodes by whatever means you prefer).

Comment: I found other way, but thanks anyway. I've written a function that's create a cubes on every cell of the map and then create a id matrix of all cubes. Indexes of every cube in the matrix equal coordinates divided in 2. With that matrix I able to refer to created cubes and deleting them when creating the floor of the rooms and tunnels.